# How to make a github pages for an organization

Tags: github, github-pages

We have an organization on github, and in one of the repo's I'm trying to convert it to a simple github.io page to present the MD files in the repo. I'm following [this guide](https://nicolas-van.github.io/easy-markdown-to-github-pages/).

It seemed easy enough, I added an `_config.yml` file to the repo and enabled github pages in the settings.

The problem is that github now shows that the site is published at our `www.ORGANIZATION_NAME.org/wiki`. But we don't own that domain. That domain isn't a registered domain in our github organization settings. I really have no clue where it got the name from, it seems completely arbitrary.

Is there any way to get a `ORGANIZATION_NAME.github.io` or similar default domain?

The message from Github settings page (organization name supplanted)

```
Your site is published at http://www.ORAGANIZATION_NAME.org/wiki/
```

Comment: On your github repo goto the settings page. In there is a section that lets you explicitly set the domain name. It is near the bottom. Search for `Custom domains allow you to serve your site from a domain other than`  Docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: I want to use `myoriganization.github.io`, this is what doesn't work. It seems that organizations MUST use a custom domain and CANNOT use the `*.github.io` domains that normal user accounts can. At least so far as I can see. What I'm asking here is whether my statement is correct, or if there is some way to enable organizations to also use `*.github.io` like individual users can?

Comment: Is your repo called `myoriganization.github.io`?

Comment: `myorganization` is a placeholder for any GitHub organization name.

Comment: I guessed that. Does not change my question. Is the repo named "XXX.github.io"?

Comment: Ah, I understand your question now, the repo is just named `myorganization`, the repo name does not contain `.github.io`. My git username is `davidparks21`, I can use domain `davidparks21.github.io` for a repo in my github account, but I don't seem to be able to do something equivalent for a repo under the organization.

Comment: The repo name needs to have the suffix: `.github.io` to be accessible via the normal URL you want: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/loki-astari.github.io

Comment: @MartinYork Oh, I see! That answers the question, you should post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Note: The `<XXX>` part can be the organization name but the repo has to belong to the organization (and the report has to have the suffix `.github.io`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use the feature where your pages are exposed on `*.github.io` you need to make sure your github repository follows the correct naming convention.

Use the repository name `<username or org-name>.github.io` the github system sees this as a "Personal Page" and exposes the repository via `https://<username or org-name>.github.io`.

see: https://pages.github.com/

You can can customize the exposed URL by adding the "CNAME" file at the root of the repository.

Example:

I have the github repository `Loki-Astari.github.io`

- Github repo:   https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Loki-Astari.github.io
- Exposed here:  https://Loki-Astari.github.io
- CNAME here:    https://LokiAstari.com

Another Example:

- Github repo:   https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io
- Exposed here:  https://academicpages.github.io